# KVM Virt network setting to be on the same network as the host?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

As described in here [How to Install KVM on Ubuntu 22.04 Step-by-Step](https://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-kvm-on-ubuntu-22-04/) I've done a series of commands:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  # add configuration for bridge interface
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp0s3]
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.162/24]
      macaddress: 08:00:27:4b:1d:45
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.2]
      parameters:
        stp: false
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

```
sudo netplan apply
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:54:e8:62:02:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.112/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 5283sec preferred_lft 5283sec
    inet6 fe80::9431:8b2a:4a7b:29c8/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:68:0e:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:4b:1d:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.162/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe4b:1d45/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:b8:09:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:feb8:96a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And then, I've set up the virtual network interface setting on the Virt Manager interface.

[image]

I thought the steps were okay, but I still don't have the internet connection.

[image]

What's wrong with the setup? Thanks for your help.

Comment: perhaps IPv4 hasn't been correctly set up in the guest?

Comment: at first plain text messages shall be sent as it is, as text, second I don't see here any business relationship or environment. So that I assume it's a home and end-user computing questions have be asked on Super User. Moreover, your guest does not seem to have a Valid ipv4